# Open source alternative for RegiStar (align, rotate, and combine images into single frame)

Tags: photography, software, alignment

I'm looking for a free, open-source and Linux compatible alternative to the [RegiStar](https://www.aurigaimaging.com/index.php) software.

I need it to automatically combine several images into a single frame, where each individual image shows a portion of a large observed region.

Individual images also overlap by some amount, and need to be aligned and possibly rotated before superimposing them onto the final frame.

I believe RegiStar does all this but: a- it is not free, b- it is not open-source, and c- it seems to run on Windows only.

Comment: In theory, you could use something like astrometry.net to find where in the stellar sphere your pictures are taken and then combine them using free software like ImageMagick. This would also account for different pictures being taken at different times (ie, Earth's rotation).

Comment: I tried astrometry.net but it won't recognize my images (they are JPEGs)

Comment: Have you tried [Montage](http://montage.ipac.caltech.edu/)? It is now under the BSD 3-Clause License.

Comment: It won't recognize them *because* they are JPEGs, or won't recognize them for other reasons? You can use ImageMagick or similar to change formats if that's the only problem.

Comment: No, it uploads the images fine. The service finds no results for at least one of my images.

Comment: @skytux I have not. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Gabriel, I may have some bash scripts using Montage, if you are interested then I can have a look... good to see that you work with Andrés P.

Comment: Thank you @skytux, I'll let you know about those scripts, much obliged. Now I'm wondering how did you know I work with AP :)

Comment: From your profile and arXiv, @Gabriel! I'm from Cba :)

Comment: I forgot my site is in my profile. Now I've looked you up too :) Saludos Germán!

Comment: Are you willing to share these images, or are they private? I/we might be able to try out a few things if you're willing to share the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had success with [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/). It's a panorama creator, but it can be used to rotate, resize, and relocate images into a coherent whole. It has a few different automated profiles, but sometimes they are a bit off with star stacks. You can manually select the guide stars though.

A really good program for after that is [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) and the plugin [G'MIC](http://gmic.eu/) to stack and remove noise.

Unfortunately it's not a single package like RegiStar, but it's free and can do quite a lot!

Before
[image: Before]

After
[image: After]

Comment: This looks promising. I could not install it manually even following the instructions given, so I ended up using a PPA. For those interested, here it is: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/install-hugin-via-ppa-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Ah, bugger! Did you manage to get it all installed finally? I use Windows primarily, so I haven't tried any of these on Linux, but I knew they could run on it

Comment: I could install it, yes. I used it for about 10 min and it crashed my system entirely. Like monster crash :( Anyway, it looks like a good tool, perhaps it just doesn't get along with Linux all that well.